# How to convert string of []bytes to []bytes

Tags: go, byte

main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    rawString := "Hello World"
    myStringBytes := fmt.Sprint([]byte(rawString))
    
    myResultString := string([]byte(myStringBytes))

    fmt.Println(myResultString)
    fmt.Println(rawString)
}
```

Output

```
[72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100]
Hello World
```

Why `myResultString` still in bytes form?

How to convert the string of []bytes to []bytes?

I want `myResultString` == `rawString`

Comment: `fmt.Sprint()` will "render" the byte slice as a space separated list of decimal numbers (enclosed in square brackets). You can't convert that back to the original `string`, you have to split the decimal numbers and parse them (convert them to integers), assemble a byte slice from them and that you can convert back to `string`.

Comment: You formatted `myResultString` like that with `fmt.Sprint`, you cannot directly convert it back, because it is not the same data. That is not a standard serialization format, so you would need to manually convert back.

Comment: So basically `fmt.Sprint()` is not a conversion, it's a function call, which transforms your byte slice. You need the inverse transformation to get the original byte slice back, which you can then convert to `string`. The standard lib has no builtin function for the inverse transformation of `fmt.Sprint()` (when you pass a byte slice).

Comment: Thank you.. now im gonna try to make function to inverse transformation from string []bytes to []bytes

Comment: Use `myStringBytes = []byte(rawString)` to get `rawString` as a `[]byte`.  Use `myResultString := string(myStringBytes)` to convert that `[]byte` back to a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used this function to resolve this problem.
Fyi, I used this method to parse semi colon query param from HTML request (:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strconv"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
    rawString := "Hello World"
    myStringBytes := fmt.Sprint([]byte(rawString))
    
    myResultString, _ := string(StringBytesParseString(myStringBytes))

    fmt.Println(myResultString)
    fmt.Println(rawString)
}

func StringBytesParseString(byteString string) (string, error) {
    byteString = strings.TrimSuffix(byteString, "]")
    byteString = strings.TrimLeft(byteString, "[")
    sByteString := strings.Split(byteString, " ")
    var res []byte
    for _, s := range sByteString {
        i, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        res = append(res, byte(i))
    }

    return string(res), nil
}
```